# SSRS 2005 report access failure from local machine

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2005 on Windows Server 2008. I have a local user account from which I can run the reports from another machine.

However, when I'm on the same machine, I cannot see the reports (the `/reports` page only shows the header and no report).

I'm using Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation for authentication of SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the browser on the server isn't passing your credentials to the SSRS service. Assuming you're using Internet Explorer, Have you tried adding the server to the list of trusted sites?

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that but it works just fine if I run IE as an Administrator (the run as administrator option). 
This behaviour is only shown on Windows Server 2008 so I guess there's a "security feature" playing silly bugger.
Anyway we had to move SSRS to another server for license purposes so the problem is irrelevant now.